# Azure DevOps Server 2019 - Continuous Deployment only if Pull Request Completes

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment

I have a CI / CD Pipeline configured in Azure DevOps Server 2019.

As soon as a pull request is created a new artifact triggers a release which deploys to the development server even if the pull request is not accepted. How can I restrict the release to server to only when pull request is completed.

Comment: Have you checked the following reply? Is it helpful?

Comment: Nope. Instead what I ended up doing is creating two build pipelines. One that has CI Trigger Enabled on It. I have created all my release pipelines on the completion of this CI Triggered Pipeline. Only challenge I am seeing is that I have to build the same code twice.

Comment: I also would like to know a more efficient way to achieve this instead of having to create another branch.

Answer (score 0):

From you release definition, you can filter the continuous integration to only run for some branches (only your main branch for instance). You will find more information about how to configure it in the [Azure DevOps documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/triggers?view=azure-devops)